# Page design distorts on Navigating back - WPF - Xamarin Forms

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms

I have included a WPF project within the Xamarin Forms project. It works fine in UWP and Android (I have not yet tested in iOS). But for WPF it causes issues.

I have a list view that has image and text. When the page loads initially, it displays fine. If I navigate to another page and hit back to come to this page, the design distorts, i.e. The text overlaps the image.
I have added a link to an image that displays the list view
[Image that shows the list when the page is loaded the first time and when it is navigated back to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjxb1.png)

> ```
>                        </Image>
>                      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
>                        <Label Text="{Binding ListName}" Font="18"></Label>
>                        <Label Text="{Binding ListDescription}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
>                  </StackLayout>
>        </StackLayout>
>                                         </ViewCell>                                  
>        </DataTemplate>
>      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>    </ListView>
>  </StackLayout>
> ```

```
On ItemTapped, this line is called
```

> ```
>   await Navigation.PushAsync(new TagListDetails());
> ```

```
        This opens the new page. Now on Click of Back on this page when it comes to this calling page, the design distorts.
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please see the updates. I have added the code.

Comment: I have the same problem Happening on Xamarin.Forms.